# php mysql data table save and edit on same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i have data table, which has 5 rows and 5 rows has save and edit options separately. on submit it is submiting in the database and page is getting refreshed. but it should not refresh and on clicking update it should be updated in the same page.
Help is appreciated.

Below is my code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['save'])!="")
{
  $workname=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['workname']);   
  $assignto=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
  $phoneno=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone_no']);
  $emailid=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['emails']);
  $issuedate=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['issue_date']);
  $deldate=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['delivery_date']);
  $actualdeldate=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['actual_delivery_date']);
  $remstrtfrm=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['reminder_start']);
  $remtmeint=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['reminder_time']);
  $remmsg=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['reminder_message']);
  $wrkstat=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['work_status']);
  $maker_id=mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['ADMIN_GAME_ID']);

 $create=mysql_query("INSERT INTO     dizypro_work_status_details(jobname,assign_to,phone_no,email_id,issue_date,delev    ry_date,actual_del_date,
    rem_strt_frm,reminder_time,reminder_message,work_status,maker_id,maker_date,row_    no)     VALUES('$workname','$assignto','$phoneno','$emailid','$issuedate','$deldate','$a    ctualdeldate','$remstrtfrm','$remtmeint','$remmsg','$wrkstat','$maker_id',now(),    '$row')");



 if($create)
  {
  $msg="Successfully Updated!!";
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$msg');</script>";
  header('Location:add-work-detail.php');
  }
  else
  {
 $errormsg="Something went wrong, Try again";
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$errormsg');</script>";
  }
  }

?>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['edit'])!="")
{
  $checkbox=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['check']);  
  $assignto=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
  $phoneno=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone_no']);
  $emailid=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['emails']);
  $issuedate=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['issue_date']);
  $deldate=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['delivery_date']);
  $actualdeldate=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['actual_delivery_date']);
  $remstrtfrm=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['reminder_start']);
  $remtmeint=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['reminder_time']);
  $remmsg=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['reminder_message']);
  $wrkstat=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['work_status']);
  $maker_id=mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['ADMIN_GAME_ID']);

 $update=mysql_query("UPDATE     dizypro_work_status_details(check_box,jobname,assign_to,phone_no,email_id,issue_    date,delevry_date,actual_del_date,
    rem_strt_frm,reminder_time,reminder_message,work_status,maker_id,maker_date,row_    no)     VALUES('$checkbox','$work_name','$assignto','$phoneno','$emailid','$issuedate','        $deldate','$actualdeldate','$remstrtfrm','$remtmeint','$remmsg','$wrkstat','$mak    er_id',now(),'$row') WHERE maker_id='".$_SESSION['ADMIN_GAME_ID']."'");



 if($update)
  {
  $msg="Successfully Updated!!";
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$msg');</script>";
  header('Location:add-work-detail.php');
  }
  else
  {
 $errormsg="Something went wrong, Try again";
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$errormsg');</script>";
  }
  }

?>
```

Screenshot:

[screenshot of form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5kYF.png)

Comment: You need to use [Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) for this.

Comment: `isset()` does NOT return a string. it returns a boolean false/true.

Comment: can you just suggest me how to get a ajax call for this?

Comment: Read the link I sent, google a bit and give it a shot. If you get stuck, come back and show us what you've tried and we'll help you. We're not here to write the code for you.

Comment: thank you....i have done this but on update it wil popup a update page but to do it in the same page i get stuck.i vil try it once.

Answer (score 0):

use ajax, you can find a simple tutorial and what is ajax? from http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/
or for simplicity, use jQuery post() Method http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp

Comment: thanks for your answer. i know to load data without reloading ajax should be used...but i thought of something without using ajax.

Comment: without using ajax? hmm I don't know another method but may be can use websocket. But as my knowledge in case of these problem best method is ajax.